# One of the partitions of my hard drive shows its empty after booting after a forced shutdown,

Tags: windows, hard-drive, chkdsk

**TL;DR**: Computer was forces shut down, came back to an empty drive (the other partition of that same disk is fine) but the properties window says its 899GB / 1TB used, tried chkdsk and all can't seem to fix it.

---

**More details**:

My PC was turned on downloading a game and I went outside to get some food. When I came back it was turned off (somebody had yanked the power cord out of the wall socket).

When I turned it on, my PC gave me the checkdisk screen before the login screen which was weird since the drive is three-four months old (Seagate Barracuda ST2000DM008, if that matters at all) and I hadn't experienced this before. Coming to the point, after logging in I tried running a game from Steam and it asked me where to download it.

I went to my drive and it showed there were no files there and the drive was empty, which was odd since I can still see the utilized space 899GB / 1TB.

I have two disks, one 250gb SSD and a 2tb standard HDD which I had partitioned into two drives. Here is a drive manager screen which shows all drives, partitions and disks as healthy.

No, the files are not hidden. Yes I tried running chksdk manually from the command prompt with admin priviliges.

Please help me out and point me how to fix it because I have some very important data on it which I have not backed up anywhere and I cannot fathom downloading all those games again since I don't have super fast internet.

Here are some pictures to further clarify my post:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) and then a couple of other [file recovery products](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-data-recovery-file-undelete-utility.htm). Don't do anything to the disk except running rescue utilities, chkdsk was already pushing it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

My best bet is a corrupt SDD. Try to reinstall some drivers, mess around with some settings, or even take a backup and then reinstall windows (not resetting but reinstalling.)

if nothing of the above works I'm afraid you have to bu a new SSD, though reinstalling windows should solve everything software related, So you if your pc is as new as you say you can probably complain to the manufacturer and get a refund if reinstalling windows doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

In addition to running chksdk, these two methods may help:

1. Use File Manager to repair: Open File Manager> select the name of your hard drive> right click, select Properties> "Tools"> "Error Checking"> "Check"> Wait for the run to complete> "Repair this Drive"> Finish .
2. Repair using CMD Line: Win + R> Type cmd in the command box to open the CMD window> Type wmic> Enter> Type disk drive to get status> Enter again.
   It is difficult for CMD to determine the condition of each hard drive. If you want to get detailed information, you can use CrystalDiskInfo or other reliable tools to check it.

In addition, there are [other repair methods](https://www.fonecope.com/how-to-fix-a-corrupted-hard-drive.html) you can refer to. In the case of trying multiple repair methods fails, you better consider recovering hard drive data.

Answer (score 0):

Since the drive shows lots of space used it can read the allocation table which makes it likely at least most of the data is there.  The numbers are wrong, though--there is a problem with the data.

Given the stated failure I suspect there was a failure when writing something at the root of the file system.  Simpler tools try to walk the directory structure and since they can't even start down that path they see nothing.  The only way to find the data is search the whole drive for things that look like a file system.

Personally, I have used https://www.r-tt.com/ successfully twice in related situations (in one case I had a failed RAID card, the data was there but the partition wasn't where Windows expected it, in the other a failed card had zeroed the first sector of every drive in the array.)  It also has a very nice feature that the trial mode shows you exactly what it can do.  (It just won't actually recover anything over 64k.)  I'm sure there are other such tools since I made my evaluation long ago but I do not know them.